# What is the purpose of _virtual_includes in bazel?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bazel, clangd

I'm using clangd navigation in VSCode. But sometimes instead of the original header of some entity it sends me to a copy of the header inside the directory `.../.bazel/.../_virtual_includes/.../MyHeader.h`. What are these `_virtual_includes` and is it possible to go directly to the original headers?

Comment: Purpose? Seems to be related to putting desired headers together when using `include_prefix` and `strip_include_prefix` attributes of `cc_library`. Which sounds like a plausible reason. There is a solution in place to report (original) location for coverage (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6254), but otherwise couple attempts to ask for generic alternative seems to have stalled: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10845, https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11874.